# Regex usage to create new column in sql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a column in SQL table as below:

```
Column_name
123.ten.abc.Testing
1245.eng.xyz.sleeping
```

Now I want to populate a column that extracts the column values until last occurrence of dot(.) and populate in new column.
So My new column should be like below

```
New_column
123.ten.abc
1245.eng.xyz
```

How can we achieve that using regex in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this without regex:

```
update your_table
set new_column = SUBSTR(old_column, 1,
                   LENGTH(old_column) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(old_column)));
```

If you want to insert the values as new rows, use:

```
Insert into your_table (new_column)
Select SUBSTR(old_column, 1,
                   LENGTH(old_column) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(old_column)))
From your_table;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/BJNR46648)

***Note: the accepted answer is incorrect***.

Consider the case when text is `1245.eng.xyz.sleeping.sleeping`. The accepted answer will return only `1245.eng.xyz` instead of `1245.eng.xyz.sleeping`

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your `table` name is test and column name is `value`, here's how we can do it:

- Get the substring after the last `.`:

  `select SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '.', -1) from test;`
- Now, as MySQL does not have a function to get the `last occurance` of a string from another string, we need to `reverse` the string and get the first occurance. So, `reverse` whatever we got from previous step and get the length

  `select LENGTH(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '.', -1))) from test;`
- Once this is done, we can reverse the whole string, get the substring from length (found in previous step) which would trim the last occurance of that word and `reverse` it again:

  `SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(value), LENGTH(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '.', -1)))+2)) from test;`

This would give you the desired output. Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/982250/1/0)**.

Once you have this value, you can execute `INSERT INTO.. SELECT` statement to insert the values, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (new_value) 
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTR(REVERSE(value), LENGTH(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '.', -1)))+2)) from test;
```

**Update**

**Answer updated to cover the edge case pointed by @GurV.**

Comment: What if the substring you found is present two or more times? It won't work.