# how to copy from one column to another but with different data in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have a table `city` and columns `name` , `id` and `address`.

| name | id | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hamburg | 05088 | 45478, AachenerStr 128 num. +49(xxx)xxxxxxx |

My question is how can i select only numbers from column `address` and copy it to new column `numbers`?
like this:

| name | id | address | numbers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hamburg | 05088 | 45478, AachenerStr 128 num. +49(xxx)xxxxxxx | +49(xxx)xxxxxxx |

Comment: You Mean you want to extract Mobile Number ?

Comment: @Roshan i want to keep mobile number in address as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x)

Comment: [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @PatrickArtner not sure. Because some address column has extra info like building numbers etc.

Comment: @first - well if some addressen contain the eyecolor of the inhabitants ... don't YOU think that would be worthwhile to be mentioned in your "demo data set of 1 line" ? You may want to add a comprehensive example of the data you are handling. Any solution proposed on missing information by you will always be lacking ;)

Comment: Does your sample data truly represent your requirements? Your new columns is "numbers" - plural, so could there be more than one? Are numbers always formatted with a `+` prefix? Are numbers always last in the address? Can a `+` appear where it's not a number prefix? etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex usage to create new column in Sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42145017/regex-usage-to-create-new-column-in-sql) - or [using-regex-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58460263/7505395)you may need to find a regex that captures 95+% of your given telefone numbers which is not trivial:  `+497611234567 +49(761)1234567 +49-761-1234567  +49 761 123 45 67`  etc

Answer (score 0):

1. If the Length of the Mobile Number is fixed and Always last in position you can use

   `Select RIGHT(address,15)`
2. Extract using the + Symbol.

   ```
   declare @address varchar(1000) = '45478, AachenerStr 128 num. +49(xxx)xxxxxxx'
   select substring(@address,CHARINDEX('+',@address),len(@address))
   ```

Comment: Yes the length of the number is fixed and last in position